# Having the closing delimiter same of the opening one without capturing it

Tags: regex

I have this regex ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/u2HzZw/3)):

```
\[quote((?:\s[a-z]+=["'][[:space:]\w]+["'])+)*\](.*?)\[\/quote\]
```

That basically let me add multiple parameters on a BBCode quote tag and allow two captures: the parameters (that will be sliced/exploded and formatted) and the content of the tag. Parameters have to be inside a single quote or a double quote in order to be fetched.

How can I make that the opening quote have to be of the same type of the closed one?. For example, if I open with a double quote, when I close, I can close just with a double quote and single quote should not be accepted. All this without capturing it, because I don't want to have useless matches.

Thanks, any advice also to improve the regex is accepted!

Comment: did I said something wrong to have a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your quote into group – `(['"])` or named group `(?<quote>['"])` and later you can add a back-reference to the group match by index `\2` or by name `\k<quote>`.  Please note, [named group syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html) can be different depending on the regex engine you are using.

Example:
`^(['"])\w+\1$`
will match `"abc"` but not `"abc'`